# What is the correct capitalisation of the following

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Company name — "Mushroom Joinery"
Tag line — "Creation and restoration in wood"

Should capitals be used in the tag line? If so, where?

Comment: As you like. There are no sentences there, so no rules need apply.

Comment: From the typesetting standpoint, you must capitalize as little as possible, because that makes it harder on the eye. Names are capitalized, but a tagline is not a name and there is no reason whatsoever to capitalize it except to (not-so-)subliminally annoy your readers. But that's typesetting, and so off-topic here. As far as the language is concerned, this is a matter of style, and there are lots of different styles as mentioned in the linked question. You can pick whichever you like, as long as you stick to it. (And if you don't ensure consistency, then it plain does not matter.)